# Why cassandra SStable stored in binary?

Tags: cassandra

I created a Cassandra table emp and got the following files for this table.

C:\Program Files\DataStax Community\data\data\tutorialspoint\emp-ff43ef908c9b11e5b64c99744aed26ea

```
      tutorialspoint-emp-ka-1-CompressionInfo.db
      tutorialspoint-emp-ka-1-Data.db
      tutorialspoint-emp-ka-1-Digest.sha1
      tutorialspoint-emp-ka-1-Filter.db
      tutorialspoint-emp-ka-1-Index.db
      tutorialspoint-emp-ka-1-Statistics.db
      tutorialspoint-emp-ka-1-Summary.db
      tutorialspoint-emp-ka-1-TOC.txt
```

I got some questions as below

1. What does '-ka' portion mean in the files name?
2. data.db is supposed to be sorted string but when I open it with nodepad it is actually in binary. Why?
3. Are all.db files supposed to be in binary format or Java byte code?

Comment: 'ka' is the version of the sstable. They are stored in binary, not sorted string Although if you had text data you could read it but it looks like you are using compression so need to disable that first.

Comment: Chris, Thanks for the answer. I recreated the table with compression disabled and I can read the text data. Cheers